# Resize NTFS partition to include unused space - GParted - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, ntfs, gparted

I have cloned my 40GB HDD to my 320GB HDD via `dd` and now I am wondering how can I expand the 34GB NTFS partition to include the unused 260GB of free space? Thanks :)

[image: 1]

Comment: What's that FAT32 partition in the middle? You'll need to move it to the right so the unallocated space is adjacent to the 34GB partition, which you can then expand.

Comment: @Karan Something called CTOS or CP/M according to `fdisk -l`... this is from a preformatted Dell HDD so I guess I don't need it?

Comment: That's most likely the Dell System Restore partition.

Comment: @Karan I'll keep it and move it to the right like you said. After I move it successfully, I can expand the NTFS 34GB with all of the unused space, correct?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do so once there's nothing in the way.

Comment: @Karan it expanded, I'll boot into Windows and report back :D post it as an answer so I can give you points :)

Comment: Will do. ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the intervening partition to the right i.e. end of the drive and then you can expand the 34GB partition once it is adjacent to the unallocated space.

You should still be able to boot into Windows. Worst-case, you might have to run Startup Repair from the Windows DVD, and then Boot Repair from a Ubuntu LiveCD.

Comment: Worked! Using the exact copy of Windows on the new HDD :D